Public request through odoo controller does throw an error: ValueError: Expected singleton: res.users()
I am trying to add a controller in odoo code that does accept few values to create a lead.
My controller code is:
@http.route('/v1/sg/book_a_demo', type='json', auth='none',  methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'],
            cors='*', csrf=False)
def handle_book_a_demo_request(self):
    lead = request.env["crm.lead"]
    partner = request.env["res.partner"]
    data = json.loads(request.httprequest.data)
    if data:
        name = data.get('name')
        address = data.get('address')
        phone = data.get('phone')
        email = data.get('email')
        business_name = data.get('business_name')
        business_abn = data.get('business_abn')
        captcha_token = data.get('captcha_token')
        individual_vals = {
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'phone': phone,
            'address': address,
            'company_type': 'person',
            'total_properties': data.get('total_properties'),
            'comment': data.get('message'),
            'parent_id': company_partner.id,
        }
        individual_id = partner.sudo().create(individual_vals)

        lead_vals = {
            'name': individual_id.name,
            'partner_id': individual_id.id,
            'source_id': request.env.ref('sg_crm.demo_request_source').id,
            'type': 'lead',
            'stage_id': crm_new_stage,
            'total_properties': data.get('total_properties'),
            'description': data.get('message')
        }
        lead_id = lead.sudo().create(lead_vals)
        response = {
            'status': 200,
            'id': lead_id.id,
        }
        result_response = {
            'result': [response]
        }
        return result_response

However When I hit this controller through postman:
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": "123 Main Street",
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "email": "johndoe@example.com",
    "business_name": "ABC Company",
    "business_abn": "123456789",
    "captcha_token": "your_captcha_token_here",
    "total_properties": "5",
    "message": "This is a demo request message"
}

It does throw following traceback to my console:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo/server/odoo/models.py", line 5158, in ensure_one
_id, = self._ids
^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/odoo/server/odoo/api.py", line 414, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/odoo/server/addons/crm_iap_enrich/models/crm_lead.py", line 43, in create
    leads = super(Lead, self).create(vals_list)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-237>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo/server/odoo/api.py", line 415, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/odoo/server/addons/crm/models/crm_lead.py", line 713, in create
    leads = super(Lead, self).create(vals_list)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-139>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo/server/odoo/api.py", line 415, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/odoo/server/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 284, in create
    thread.sudo().message_post(subtype_id=subtype.id, author_id=self.env.user.partner_id.id)
  File "/opt/odoo/server/addons/rating/models/mail_thread.py", line 15, in message_post
    message = super(MailThread, self).message_post(**kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/odoo/server/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 2000, in message_post
    if self.env.user._is_public() and guest:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/odoo/server/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 1053, in _is_public
    self.ensure_one()
  File "/opt/odoo/server/odoo/models.py", line 5161, in ensure_one
    raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: res.users()

This is very awkward. I can confirm that individual_id partner was successfully created but it's struggling while creating a lead object in odoo. can anyone please help me here. Thanks in advance

When setting the auth to none the request code will not have any facilities to access the current user.
from the Routing documentation section:

auth (str) –The authentication method, one of the following:    user: The user must be authenticated and the current request will be executed using the rights of     the user.    public: The user may or may not be authenticated. If he isn’t, the current request will be     executed using the shared Public user.   none: The method is always active, even if there is no database. Mainly used by the framework     and authentication modules. The request code will not have any facilities to access the current     user.


If you plan to leave your controller's auth='none' alone, you can resolve the problem by generating the record with the with_user() method.
from odoo import http, fields, SUPERUSER_ID

lead_id = lead.with_user(SUPERUSER_ID).create(lead_vals)

